# Can I curl down a transparent overlay image that looks transparent in the animation?

Tags: ios, animation, uiview, calayer, transition

Currently I am using UIView's +transitionWithView method to add an overlay by adding a UIImageView that contains a transparent image as a subview of my main view.  I am using the curl down transition option.  The problem is that this transitioning method is opaque, that is it is curling down the "after" view on top of the "before" view.  Is there a way to curl down and peel off a transparent image like transparency sheets for an overhead projector?

Thanks!

Comment: Change the `alpha` to `0.2` or something low-ish.

Comment: The `UIView` that is doing the transition.